# How do I send an Exact Target Email Template to a list of emails?

Tags: javascript, api, salesforce, exacttarget

I am trying to build a simple email application using Javascript to go against either the ExactTarget SOAP or REST API. Our goal is to use only Exact Target to build email templates and then send those email templates to a list of subscribers (passed in via an array or JSON object). My question is does the ExactTarget API even have the ability to do this? From what I have seen the only option is sendDefinitions or TriggeredEmails none of which are the type of functionality we are looking for. If the functionality exists what is the API endpoint I would hit and what would the body look like?

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [Marketing-Cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) tag.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122449/exacttarget-is-it-possible-to-send-template-email-to-list-of-users that was the first place I looked but got no traction

Comment: I answered your question over on SFSE.